# Clearing variable after event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I've got my code working. I'm trying to add up the input from a text area which works. But the variable `values` is holding on to its value after every onclick event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var values = "";
        var stat = new Object();
        stat.sum = "0";
        stat.sumSquare = "0";
        stat.grabInput = function() {
            values = "0";
            var txtValues = document.getElementById("txtInput");
            values = txtValues.value;
            values = values.split(" ");
        }
        stat.adder = function() {
            for (i=0;i<values.length;i++){
                stat.sum=parseFloat(stat.sum)+parseFloat(values[i]);
            }
        }
        stat.squareAdder = function() {
            for (i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
                stat.sumSquare=parseFloat(stat.sumSquare)+(parseFloat(values[i])*parseFloat(values[i]));
            }
        }
        stat.showSum = function() {
            stat.grabInput();
            stat.adder();
            document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = "The sum is: "+stat.sum+"<br />";
        }
        stat.showSquareSum = function() {
            stat.grabInput();
            stat.squareAdder();
            document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = "The squared sum is: "+stat.sumSquare;
        }
    </script>
    <form action="">
        <fieldset>
            <textarea id="txtInput" name="txtInput"></textarea>
            <input type="button" value="Sum" onClick="stat.showSum();" />
            <input type="button" value="Square Sum" onClick="stat.showSquareSum();" />
        </fieldset>
        <div id="answers"></div>
    </form>
```

I just don't know why the `values = "0";` wouldn't reset the it back to 0.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `values = "0";` is working as it is suppose to work.. It sets the `values` variable to `0` initially... You never set it to `0` later in your code..

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just figured out that I wasn't resetting `stat.sum` and `stat.sumSquare` after each onclick event.

```
stat.adder = function() {
            stat.sum = "0";
            for (i=0;i<values.length;i++){
                stat.sum=parseFloat(stat.sum)+parseFloat(values[i]);
            }
        }
        stat.squareAdder = function() {
            stat.sumSquare = "0";
            for (i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
                stat.sumSquare=parseFloat(stat.sumSquare)+(parseFloat(values[i])*parseFloat(values[i]));
            }
        }
```

Now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring value = "0" on each onclick . thats why its holding "0"